# iOS Push notification with video is not showing on lock screen

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, push

I am testing notification service extension on iphone 7 (iOS 13.4). I am sending multiples media types (jpg, gif and mp4). The content with jpg and gif are showing good, but mp4 notification only shows content when iphone is unlocked. When iphone is locked and notification video played the image is not showing, white screen all the time, although the video is heard. if I press the touch button while video is playing with white screen the image appears.

In the notification settings for the app all permissions are granted (I think).

Do I have to ask the user for any special permissions? Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to write give permission during write completeFileProtectionUntilFirstUserAuthentication.

Below is the sample code:

```
`extension UNNotificationAttachment {
  convenience init(gifData: Data, options: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) throws {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let temporaryFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
    let temporaryFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(temporaryFolderName, isDirectory: true)
    try fileManager.createDirectory(at: temporaryFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    let imageFileIdentifier = UUID().uuidString + ".mp4"
    let fileURL = temporaryFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
    try gifData.write(to: fileURL, options: .completeFileProtectionUntilFirstUserAuthentication)
    try self.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
  }
}`
```